# Specifying which divs are shown according to the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition

First of all, I'm a beginning coder, so please bear with me.

I've done my research and I've found several ways to do this, but for some reason nothing works for me. I have to create a webshop for a school assignment and I coded all pages in hidden divs so that the page jump transition won't be there.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/
This is basically what I'm trying to do.

```
<div id="menshirts" class="page content">
    <div id="innercontent">

    </div><!--innercontent-->
    </div><!--menshirts-->
```

I have a div such as the one shown above for all pages, but now I just need the URL to correspond to that for better navigation. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: in the demo http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html#portfolio when you click a link and reload the page, it loads page properly. have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already checked out the [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/intro) ?
It basically allows you to define routes at the front end so users can bookmark the url and events can be triggered.
If you search the net, you will find other libraries that can do the same thing for you.

You should be able to do something (simplified) like:

```
    //Initialize sammy 
    App = $.sammy("#wrapper", function() {
        this.get('#home', function(){getRouter('home');});
    }

    //-> this code gets executed when the user clicks #home (anchor) within the wrapper 
    //You can do here whatever you want basically. 
    function getRouter(routerName){
        var page = routerName;
        //code to fadeIn/Show page based on identifier 
    }
```

Comment: Sammy seems like a nice way to do it, but it speaks of "get"-routes, and frankly I've never heard of those. The way I've been doing it now is by using .animate and .fadeIn/Out.

Comment: I think I'll figure it out if I mess around with this a little! Thank you!